# uiscrollview scrollViewWillBeginDragging messes up uitableview custom cells height

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a searchBar (with scopeBar) where I want to dismiss the keyboard when the server returns relevant results.  I have the following code:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [search resignFirstResponder];

    //height - navBar - searchBar - carrierBar - uitabbar
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 44, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-44-44-20-49);
    homeTable.frame = newFrame;


}
```

and

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar { 
    //[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = kScopeButtonTitles;
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;  
    [searchBar sizeToFit];  

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];  

    //resize the table for the scope bar
    //uitabbar height is 49
    //uinavigationbar is 44
    //uisearchbar and scope is 44 each
    //UIkeyboard is 216
    //UITabBar is covered by UIKeyboard, so it doesn't have to be subtracted.
    //carrier status bar is 20

    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 88, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-44-88-216-20);
    homeTable.frame = newFrame;

}
```

When the server returns the data, I call

```
[homeTable reloadData];
```

whereupon my `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called - 10x to be exact.

Scrolling the table will dismiss the keyboard, but I notice that the heights are all messed up.  In the debugger, I noticed that

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

uses a fresh cell different than the one used in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` every time.

Is this an error?

I notice that if I don't call the `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` method, the uitableviewcell heights are all fine, even after reloading the table.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind.  I realized that the table calls `searchBarTextDidEndEditing`, whereupon i was doing some extra things in there.